# Calculating decimal digits by hand for extremely large numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

On the most recent Seton Hall Joseph W. Andrushkiw Competition, the final question was as follows:

> Let $A = (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2016}$. When A is written in decimal
>   form, what is its $31^{st}$ digit after the decimal point?

Brute forcing it via wolfram alpha reveals that the answer is [edit: I found the 31st number from the start, not the 31st after the decimal point] zero, yet this competition does not allow the use of a calculator. It seems to me that as irrational numbers are in the base of the exponent, there should not be an identifiable pattern in the digits.

<s>Searching this site has made me think that perhaps the answer has something to do with the Euler phi function (something which I will admit up front I have never been acquainted with), but</s> I can't find anything which I understand enough to give me a concrete way to start to approach this. Any help on this frustrating problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413060/complexity-of-irrational-numbers?lq=1 ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Hmm. Pretty sure that the answer is $9$.
The key observation to this problem is noticing that $(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2016}+(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2016}$ is an integer.

The proof of this is expansion using Binomial Theorem. The odd powers of the square roots get canceled out.

Now we have $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2016} = N - (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2016}$, where $N$ is a positive integer.

Now this is easy. Since $(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2016} < (0.4)^{2016} = (0.064)^{\frac{2016}{3}} < (0.1)^{\frac{2016}{3}} < (0.1)^{600}$, we have $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2016}= (N-1)+0.99\cdots 99$, and there are at least $500$ $9$'s there. The answer is $\boxed{9}$.

Comment: Very nice. +1  .

Comment: As a historical note, the key observation above derived via the binomial expansion, is also a corollary to proposition 9 book 2 of Euclid's Elements. It takes a lot more work there, but gives a nice geometrical interpretation very different in feeling (for me at least) from the binomial way to see it.

Comment: I don't get the last part. You didn't prove that $(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} )^{2016} = 0.9999$. You have only shown that it is less than $0.1^{600}$. Does that mean that eg. $0.05^{600}$, which is less than $0.1^{600}$ also has so many nines? No, only if it is in some form of: $10^{-\text{many}}$. I really don't get how you concluded that, with these inequalities. Elaborate more?

Answer (score 11):

Compare $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^n$ and $(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^n$
Can show their sum is an integer when $n$ is even, and the second number is very small?